# Can not start threads from pointer to function, C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, pointers

I am trying to start a thread execution doing the following:

```
 #include <thread>
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef void (*callback_function)(void);

 void printer(){
     printf("Something\n");
 }

 void doTask(callback_function a){
     std::thread t1(a);
 }

 int main(){
     callback_function print = printer;
     doTask(print);
 }
```

Executing this piece of code, the result is a core dumped. Surprisingly,  when I change the function doTask to this one:

```
void doTask(callback_function a){
     a();
}
```

It works, or even doing that also works:

```
int main(){
     callback_function print = printer;
     std::thread t1(printer);
}
```

Does somebody knows what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try joining the thread before your main exits?

Comment: I corrected it and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Both cases are wrong. The object `std::thread t1` *lives* until the function `doTask` exits. Then the thread object is trying to be destroying while `callback_function` still works.
You should wait for thread to stop it's work and then to delete it.

```
int main(){
    callback_function print = printer;
    std::thread t1(printer);
    // do some other stuff
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: You are right, I missed to write other lines of code of the program, and not knowing why, they "solved" the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the main thread ends before that the `t1` thread has finished its work. You should add `t1.join()` or `t1.detach()` before exiting doTask.